# How to dynamically add fields to a NSView similar to iCal New Task popup?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4, osx-lion

I'm trying to implement a NSView which will host a 'choose file' attachment button. If the user chooses to add a file, the user will be given an option to add another one (and from the 'new set of dropdowns' the user will essentially be able to pick the kind of file they're attaching').

The closest match to this functionality is iCal's New Task editor where you select an alarm and then it gives you an option to add another alarm right underneath.

What is the right way of doing this (I'm new to Mac OS X development)? I originally thought I'd create a custom NSView with all the 'file options' and then if the user was to attach a file I'd dynamically add another NSView right below it (in a NSScrollView). However so many apps do something similar that I almost feel as if there's something else out there in the set of controls that I should be using.

Please can someone guide me to the right direction? Is 'NSForm' or NSPredicateEditor used for this sort of stuff? This is what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither NSForm nor NSPredicateEditor would be useful for what you want to do. I think your thoughts about how to do this by adding a custom view below the original view, is the right way to go.  You don't necessarily have to do it in a scroll view, you could expand the size of the window like iCal does.

Comment: Thanks, however after 5 or so alerts iCal seems to allow scrolling in the same view which means the original backing view is a NSScrollView which gets activated for scroll when the content view's size increases panel bounds.